# Disabling text field for all users / roles

Tags: 8, entities, database

is there an easy way to disable (readonly) fields in the backend for ALL users and roles (also superadmin).

I already found a module -> https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_field but this module allows superadmins to edit the fields.

**Why do i need this?**

Because the 5star rating module isn't ported to D8 yet i need a solution to realize a 5star voting in D8 with the vote data (5star rating) from an old drupal installation.

My thought was to work with a field collection, where i want to import the main 5star rating values from the old site into the new installation.

Afterwards i want to build a custom 5star voting.

The users should not be able to change this values in the field collection.

Any ideas?

Regards

M.

Comment: What about removing the fields in *Manage form display* of the field collection? If you want to be sure, you can set `$form['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;` in a form alter hook.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh sounds nice... i've totally forgotten that i could handle it this way! thx for the hint! i'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you need to disable any fields in the first place (that's not turns out from your post), but if you need 5 voting field, you could easily create it:

You may need just a part of them or all of them:

[Creating a custom Field](https://www.drupal.org/node/2620964)

Comment: It's quite easy:
Disabeling the fields therefore, that nobody can change the vote results.

I don't want to add a new field, i want to work with existing fields, like text etc. combined with the field collection module.

Now it looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xp3xyx8o5m5vai/Screenshot%202016-09-21%2014.23.35.png?dl=0